# Excel: Power Query >Table resizing to fit results > Havoc with conditional formatting

Tags: microsoft-excel, conditional-formatting, size

Hello and thank you for your time.
Excel in Office 365 Version 1904
In a nutshell:

1. Power Query (PQ) pulls a lot of data into a hidden table.
2. Other PQs reference this data to pull what we need for different places in the workbook.
3. One PQ sorts out the line items of an order into three columns, A, B and C, resizing the table to fit the number of rows in the table to match the number of line items in the order:

[image: Picture of the table example]

Column C will have one of several reference types like "Repeat" or "First Time".
In our dev meetings we use the blank cells next to this table to answer questions about the "First Time" development line item. We only need to enter data for "First Time" line items. So I want to use cells in column C to conditionally format cells in column D-I to grey if it isn't a "First time" item.

example: If C9 is "Repeat", then D9-I9 get grey fill. Then move to the next line: IF C10 if "Repeat" then D10-I10 Get grey fill.

The Problem: When I run the query to load the line items, the table auto resizes and it seems to displace anything I put in place to just below the table. Adds weird conditional formatting rules or displaces the a formula cell reference or some infuriating and confusing thing.

I have tried a lot of things that seem to only increase complexity, never touching the problem of the table resize moving the cell reference. Conditional formatting seems to almost work most of the time, but it is also always messed up somehow by the table resizing.

It seems easy, if this cell says "Repeat" then grey out these 6 cells in the row next to it.
But excel gets confused because things outside the table reference cells inside a table that changes size.
Alas, I can't figure out how the elegant and robust solution.
How would you do it?

Thoughts?

Comment: On a PQ table, I set up conditional formatting and could not reproduce your problem. My CF formula was created for the first data row using regular addressing; and the `Applies to` refers to the `Table`

Comment: Thank you for trying. So using the table in the image as a reference for this comment: you were able to reference information from column "C9" (Included in the table that resizes) to set CF that "greyed out" D9-I9 (Not included in the table that resizes). And this persisted with table resizing? I will have to go back and see what I am missing here. Thank you again for taking the time.

Comment: It persists with Table resizing caused by adding/deleting rows from the source table, and then doing a refresh on the query.